# Limit which user can sign in using Omniauth-twitter

Tags: ruby, twitter, sinatra, omniauth

Im building a simple app and need to add authentication. I was wondering if it was possible within omniauth to limit users that can sign in with twitter by their usernames.

My aim is to only allow a few pre-select people into the backend of this app.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you already have some strategy to manage users signing in with twitter. If not, you might wanna check out this [raislcast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth).

Once a user signs in with twitter, twitter will forward you a hash of that user object.  You can access it via `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` and decide if you want to create a user object for a particular username.